# Why do I still get an ArrayList.<init> error when use ArrayList.add(Object) in a for loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add objects to my ArrayList *coupleList* but I keep getting the  error.

**Constructor for my WordCouple class**

```
    public class WordCouple {

    private String first;
    private String second;

    public WordCouple (String first, String second) {
        first = this.first;
        second = this.second;
    }
```

**Constructor for my WordCoupleList class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class WordCoupleList {

    private ArrayList<WordCouple> coupleList;


    public WordCoupleList(String[] words) {


        for(int i = 0; i < words.length -1; i ++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {


                coupleList.add(new WordCouple(words[i], words[i+j]));

            }
        }

    }
```

What I'm trying to do is make all possible `WordCouple` instances from a `String array`,  and place them in an `ArrayList` but I can't seem to initialize the `ArrayList`.

Example: the `WordCoupleList` constructor was passed an array like: `{dog, cat, the ,cat}` then the `ArrayList` would look like `[(dog,cat), (dog,the), (dog,cat), (cat,the), (cat,cat), (the,cat)`.  Each word in the array must make a couple with the other words that exist later in the array.

Comment: Please post the exact exception you're getting, including the stack trace.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 6):

Because

```
private ArrayList<WordCouple> coupleList;
```

declares a variable of type `ArrayList` but does not initialize it (so it is null). You need something like

```
private ArrayList<WordCouple> coupleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**or**, better, prefer the `List` interface like

```
private List<WordCouple> coupleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**or** just initialize it in your constructor. Like,

```
public WordCoupleList(String[] words) {
    coupleList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            coupleList.add(new WordCouple(words[i], words[i + j]));
        }
    }
}
```